# Can't run custom component in React native

Tags: android

Need some help with React Native. Searched in Google, but didn't find any solution.
 I have one project which works on android. Here code:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      AppRegistry,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View
    } from 'react-native';
    export default class MyApp extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
              Welcome to React Native!
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              To get started, edit index.android.js
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,{'\n'}
              Shake or press menu button for dev menu
            </Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      },
      welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
      },
      instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
      },
    });

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

But when i try to add my own component it  like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import MainPage from "./app/components/MainPage/MainPage";

export default class MyApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,{'\n'}
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>

        <MainPage/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

i get error in emulator:
[image]

Can somebody help?
Code for component MainPage:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class MainPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                    Welcome to React Native!
                </Text>

            </View>
        );
    }
}

MainPage.propTypes = {}

MainPage.defaultProps = {}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MainPage', () => MainPage);
```

Comment: Your problem seem to be the path of your file on your module import. Make sure that it is the right one.

Comment: It is right. I checked it. I can't understand why it happens, because path is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution. It was because of file format. It should be .js and not .jsx. After this correction all works fine. I hope it will help someone